# how to change colour of arrow in uitableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want that the arrow of Tablecell is visible permanently. currently it is visible only on selection.
secondly i want to change its colour from white to orrange.

How i will do this.

Regards
Nauman k

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer here:

[Which is the best way to change the color/view of disclosure indicator accessory view in a table view cell in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852672/best-way-to-change-the-color-view-of-disclosure-indicator-accessory-view-in-a-tab)