# Change the color of UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

A quick question, I want to change the color of the `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` (the arrow on the right side of `tableView`) from default gray to white color.

```
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```

Comment: Old question but had no satisfactory answer yet. Here is what you *actually* asked for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35427683/378024

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should create an image and use it instead!

cell. accessoryView = myAccessoryUIImageView;

Comment: is der any way to change the UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicato color in iphone by default

Comment: i doubt it is possible to change by default. You could subclass UITableViewCell and customize all and maybe reuse that everywhere else?

Comment: **It is possible to color the original Apple indicator:** See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35427683/378024
(without using custom images or custom drawing code)

Answer (score 4):

To change the colour of `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`:

```
cell.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: The answer may be "right" but it sadly doesn't answer the question that was asked. UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator is not the same as UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton. :(

Comment: UITableViewCell has no such method tintColor

Answer (score 3):

For others who are still stumbling upon this question, here's how to do it programmatically.

Create a UIView subclass, and override `drawRect:` with the following:

```
#define PADDING 4.f //give the canvas some padding so the ends and joints of the lines can be drawn with a mitered joint

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor grayColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.f);
    CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinMiter);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, PADDING, PADDING);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.frame.size.width - PADDING, self.frame.size.height/2);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, PADDING, self.frame.size.height - PADDING);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

This draws a stock indicator arrow. From here you can change the color, line width, etc.

To add the indicator view to your cell:

```
#define ACCESSORY_WIDTH 13.f
#define ACCESSORY_HEIGHT 18.f

cell.accessoryView = [[AccessoryIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - ACCESSORY_WIDTH - CELL_PADDING, self.frame.size.height/2 - ACCESSORY_HEIGHT/2, ACCESSORY_WIDTH, ACCESSORY_HEIGHT)];
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll find including [MSCellAccessory](https://github.com/bitmapdata/MSCellAccessory) will help in a lot of different ways including changing the color of the UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on: [Which is the best way to change the color/view of disclosure indicator accessory view in a table view cell in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852672/best-way-to-change-the-color-view-of-disclosure-indicator-accessory-view-in-a-ta)

A complete implementation is available at: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/10/custom-colored-disclosure-indicators/