# How to change color of disclosure indicator of UITableVeiw Programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I know that using `UIImageView` We can set the Disclosure Indicator Accessory, But I want to change only disclosure indicator color without using `UIImageView`.

Is it Possible or Not? If it is possible then how?

Comment: How do you mean exactly? you can always use custom cells

Comment: Old question but had no satisfactory answer yet. Here is what you actually asked for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35427702/378024

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Add your own disclosure indicator:

```
cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accessory.png"]];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I know about this but I want to change the color without using UIImageView like we can change the tint color of slider. Is it possible?

Comment: As far I know (not to much) it's not possible. Another possibility is, instead using a png, draw the indicator. Try with this link: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/10/custom-colored-disclosure-indicators/

Comment: **It is possible.** See my answer how to **color the original Apple indicator:**  http://stackoverflow.com/a/35427702/378024 (without using custom images or custom drawing code)

Comment: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/10/custom-colored-disclosure-indicators/ its worked for me.... Thank you so much RFG

Comment: @galambalazs Your answer works great, but please correct the link to be http://stackoverflow.com/a/35427599/496504

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm late to the party but I just prepared a custom view that draws a disclosure view. I've quickly made it for a demo so it might not be extremely precise, it just does the job. Hope it helps someone:

PZDisclosureIndicator.h

```
//
// Created by Pall Zoltan on 10/10/14.
// Copyright (c) 2014 pallzoltan. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PZDisclosureIndicator : UIView
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIColor *color;

- (PZDisclosureIndicator *)initWithColor:(UIColor *)color;
@end
```

PZDisclosureIndicator.m:

```
//
// Created by Pall Zoltan on 10/10/14.
// Copyright (c) 2014 pallzoltan. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PZDisclosureIndicator.h"

@interface PZDisclosureIndicator ()

@property(nonatomic) CGFloat red;
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat green;
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat blue;
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat alpha;

@end

@implementation PZDisclosureIndicator

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, self.red, self.green, self.blue, self.alpha);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 4, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 4, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 16, 12);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 4, 24);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, 24 - 4);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 9, 12);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, 4);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 4, 0);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}

- (PZDisclosureIndicator *)initWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 24)];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    self.color = color;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    return self;
}

- (void)setColor:(UIColor *)color {
    _color = color;

    [self.color getRed:&_red green:&_green blue:&_blue alpha:&_alpha];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

Then in my custom cell, I do this:

```
self.accessoryView = [[PZDisclosureIndicator alloc] initWithColor:SECONDARY_HIGHLIGHT_COLOR];
```

Theoretically you should be able to change its colour after initialisation too, haven't tried that.

Looks like this:
[image: Sample usage of the view]

Z.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! I've changed the drawing just a bit because the view was too big and the line was too thick for what I needed, other than that, it was perfect for me.

Comment: Can you include a picture? Thanks.

Comment: Or in Swift: http://pastebin.com/xgReAeWc

Comment: Works well but I agree with @AndraTodorescu in that the arrow is a bit too fat to suit the aesthetic of iOS 7+. I modified [this example's](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/10/custom-colored-disclosure-indicators/) `CGContextSetLineWidth(ctxt, 2);` to be 2 and not 4 to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I'm super super late to the party but I was struggling with this today and just figured it out (in iOS8 and 9). Using the View Debugger, it was clear the Disclosure triangle is a UIImage in a UIImageView in a UIButton.

So in -awakeFromNib, I was iterating through the subviews to find a button. Once I found the button, a reference to the original image could be acquired via -backgroundImageForState:

Once you get the original image, you can create a copy that is a Template image by calling [originalImage imageWithRenderingMode:AlwaysTemplate]

Then you can set the backgroundImage for all available states. Once you do that, the Image picks up the tint color automatically.

Below is some swift sample code:

```swift
class GratuitousDisclosureTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    private weak var disclosureButton: UIButton? {
        didSet {
            if let originalImage = self.disclosureButton?.backgroundImageForState(.Normal) {
                let templateImage = originalImage.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
                self.disclosureButton?.setBackgroundImage(templateImage, forState: .Normal)
                self.disclosureButton?.setBackgroundImage(templateImage, forState: .Highlighted)
                self.disclosureButton?.setBackgroundImage(templateImage, forState: .Disabled)
                self.disclosureButton?.setBackgroundImage(templateImage, forState: .Selected)
                self.disclosureButton?.setBackgroundImage(templateImage, forState: .Application)
                self.disclosureButton?.setBackgroundImage(templateImage, forState: .Reserved)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        for view in self.subviews {
            if let button = view as? UIButton {
                self.disclosureButton = button
                break
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I should add, that this works as long as you don't have other buttons in your cell's view hierarchy. If you do, you will need to give them a distinguishing tag or something so you can ignore them while looking for the correct button.

Comment: Adding `self.tintColor = .red` in `awakeFromNib` before stepping through the `subViews` would make this subclass a little clearer I think.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to create your own custom UIButton and set it as cell's
>   accessoryView. You cant change its color by by simply specifying its 
>   UIColor.

You can customize Disclosure Indicator by adding one image for normal state and another for selected (highlighted).

one Library for customizing Disclosure Indicator: [check here](https://github.com/bitmapdata/MSCellAccessory).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed above one way to modify an accessoryView is by adding your own UIImageView. However, in fact you can supply any object deriving from UIView. I would then recommend using a UILabel with an icon font (e.g. icomoon) instead of UIImageView. UILabel and an icon font allow for flexibility in both image, color and size.

```
let font = UIFont(name: "icomoon", size: 16.0)
let icon = "\u{e60f}"    
let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20))
lbl.font = font
lbl.text = icon
cell.accessoryView = lbl
```

Comment: doesn't work. The icon shows as ? in a box. The idea is good though

Comment: @JoãoNunes did you add icomoon to the project?

Comment: @MarkBlythe nope. If we need that, then it isn't mention in the answer.

Comment: @JoãoNunes Icomoon is a custom font, you will need to add it to the app or you will end up with '?' where the app tries to render a font it doesn't recognise. This may help a little in the future: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: @MarkBlythe Im just saying that the answer doesn't mention that you need to add a costume  font. It must be edited.

Comment: @JoãoNunes it is written here: `UIFont(name: "icomoon"`. Several people at least would recognize that not to be a font embedded by default in iOS.

Comment: @njzk2 not all apparently

Answer (score 0):

You can try with uiimageview to apply cell accessoryType like below code:

```
cell.accessoryView = myAccessoryUIImageView;
cell accessoryview uiimageview not align correctly try below code:


UIView* accessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 50)];
UIImageView* accessoryViewImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"accessory_image.png"]];
accessoryViewImage.center = CGPointMake(12, 25);
[accessoryView addSubview:accessoryViewImage];
[cell setAccessoryView:accessoryView];
```