# Coloring the disclosure indicator on a tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to color a disclosure indicator on my table view cell. I tried few different solutions, one was replacing it with an image, which not working good for me, as I need RTL support, and it just looks off, plus, the icon is way too big.
another one, Is making a custom disclosure indicator but I couldn't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with tint olor of cell hope is helps

Comment: Please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492683/how-to-change-color-of-disclosure-indicator-of-uitableveiw-programmatically