# How to change NavigationLink arrow color within Form

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

In SwiftUI, when a NavigationLink is placed inside of a Form, an arrow automatically appears on the trailing side of the NavigationLink. How can the color of this arrow be changed?

```
struct example: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Example destination")) {
                    Text("Example link")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Form`/`List` is reusing `UITableView` and it's always been a problem to change the disclosure indicator `tintColor` <sup>*See: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1852672/2857130)</sup>
So it comes to no surprise that `.accentColor` won't work here either.

The suggestions have mostly been to replace it with a custom view.
So lets do the same in `SwiftUI`.

#### Solution:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Form {
        //Overlap NavigationLink and our Custom Cell arrangement
        ZStack {
          //Create a NavigationLink without the disclosure indicator
          NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello, World!")) {
            EmptyView()
          }

          //Replicate the default cell
          HStack {
            Text("Custom UI")
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
              .resizable()
              .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
              .frame(width: 7)
              .foregroundColor(.red) //Apply color for arrow only
          }
          .foregroundColor(.purple) //Optional: Apply color on all inner elements
        }

        //Default style
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello, World!")) {
          Text("Default UI")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- `NavigationLink` with `EmptyView` gets rid of the default disclosure indicator
- `HStack` is our Custom Cell `View` that replicates the default cell arrangement

  - `Image(systemName: "chevron.right")` is our replacement for the diclosure indicator
  - `.foregroundColor` will allow us to splash a color on either the entire `HStack` or just the `Image` (your choice)
- `ZStack` allows to overlap the above two.

  - The `NavigationLink` basically makes the entire cell tappable

#### Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 9):

You can provide a custom view and hide the default NavigationLink arrow:

```
       NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello, World!")) {}
       .opacity(0)
       .background(
         HStack {
            Text("Custom UI")
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
              .resizable()
              .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
              .frame(width: 7)
              .foregroundColor(.red) //Apply color for arrow only
          }
          .foregroundColor(.purple)
       )
```

Or specify the NavigationLink as background (so you have auto sizing):

```
         HStack {
            Text("Custom UI")
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
              .resizable()
              .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
              .frame(width: 7)
              .foregroundColor(.red) //Apply color for arrow only
          }
          .foregroundColor(.purple)
          .background(
             NavigationLink(destination: Text("Hello, World!")) {}
                .opacity(0)
          )
```

Comment: This is a better solution

Comment: Solution with a NavigationLink inside a .background() works great